# How do I display text in a gtk widget without using a textbox?

Tags: c, gtk

Here is my current application

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTa8s.jpg

As you can see from the output, I am using pdcurses. In order to achieve the GPU 0 and GPU 1 lines, I use mvwprintw which allows me to specify a variable and add +1 so that it prints on the next line.

Sadly, in GTK, all I have is GTKtextview and GTKtreeview. That is not what I need. I need to print the same way gtk_label_set_text works but without overwriting the line, and printing on the next

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, you want a GtkLabel with multiple lines of text - you can do that by just setting the label to a string with newlines in it.  If you want to append a line to an existing label, first grab the existing text with `gtk_label_get_text()`, copy it and append a newline character and the next line.